# Ethernet and wireless will not work: Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit on a Gateway notebook

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, modem

I have a Gateway notebook and installed Vista on it (successfully), but cannot get my new Ubuntu 10.4 installation to connect with the internet wirelessly. I can get a list of routers (on the triangular button) and it tries its hardest to connect, but without result. The "Additional Drivers" installed with the Ubuntu 10.4 system -- located in "Applications" -- is corrupted so is of no help. I tried, in vain to search for a Linux driver on the internet, but could find none. Please, help me connect to the internet with the proper driver.
(zeller@live.com)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Do you have any network connection, or just the wireless fails? Is your system a pure 10.04 or is it updated to 10.04.3?

Answer (score 1):

Fresher kernels have more driver. So try a live cd/usb with Ubuntu 11.10.

Or if you have wired connection (that was not clear from your question) add the kernel ppa `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa && sudo apt-get update` and install `linux-image-generic-lts-backport-oneiric` Reboot, and I think your wireless should work.